# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - Same with service Adonis js runing inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, adonis.js

I finished install adonis js with cli according to the documentation, but, I can't access the main page as several examples in web. When I try access, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Obs : The port is free, i already changed the .env file ;/

I have on the same container an app with vue.js and he works perfectly !

Sorry by english, i am brazilian no time of translate ;/

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /var/www/html/node_modules/yardstick/app/**/*     /var/www/html/node_modules/yardstick/bootstrap/**/*     /var/www/html/node_modules/yardstick/config/**/* .env
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
info adonis:framework +0ms serving app on localhost:9210
```

Comment: Did you try mapping docker port to host port?

Comment: No yet .. the just thing that i did was map the host port to docker :

  ports:
    - "9210:9210" # Adonis

Comment: I will try to run in outside docker .. let's see !

Comment: It was tested puting adonis js in local host (out docker) and work perfectly .. gived a problem of proxies but i solved with `--harmony_proxies` .. 

I don`t understant why it doens`t work inside docker same all mapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the daemon is running on localhost:9210 inside the Docker container.  You must use 0.0.0.0:9210.  A Docker container usually has 2 interfaces: the loopback interface and eth0.

Comment: Thanks so much, it solved my problem ! It information about these two interfaces did you find in docker documentation ?

Comment: You must mark this question as answered...  Obrigado.